# .net connectivity with oracle

Tags: .net, connection

In how many ways we can make .net connection with oracle(along with syntax) and which is the best syntax to use and why..

Answer (score 0):

Using the System.Data.OracleClient works very effectively for me. You will need to add that reference in your project before you can include the `using System.Data.OracleClient;`

You can learn more about working with this at MSDN:
1. [Oracle Client Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATA.ORACLECLIENT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) &
2. [Oracle Connection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx)

You will need to connect, just like other dbs, [using a connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle). There are options, I use TNS as directed by our database group. It seems to be reliable and efficient but I really can't compare it to other methods. For TNS you need make sure that your TNS file contains pointers to the Oracle server (*rather like a "HOST" file*) and your connection string will look something like: `Data Source=YourOracleServer;User Id=Username;Password=Password;` Remember that with Oracle (unlike MS-SQL) you don't need to specify a database name/schema/catalog as your UserID controls what resources you have access to.

Comment: The second paragraph on MSDN about the Oracle Client Namespace says: "This types in System.Data.OracleClient are _deprecated_ and will be _removed_ in a future version of the .NET Framework. For more information, see Oracle and ADO.NET." You better have a look at Oracle's .NET client called ODP.NET.

Comment: It was not removed in version 4 so it is viable for the time being. After this question languished unanswered for a full day. Given that nobody else was offering OP _anything_ I decide to tell him about one solution that has the benefit of actually WORKING. (And Microsoft has **never** reversed course on such a decision...)